# how to find parent li in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

in BeautifulSoup I want to find the second value of a li in an element
this is my code

```
university_rank_s = "#StudyOrganisationLocation .OrganisationRanking"
university_rank_st = page.select(university_rank_s)[0].text.strip() if page.select(university_rank_s) else 'N/A'
university_rank = get_no_from_str(university_rank_st)
```

Comment: what does function `get_no_from_str` do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your code to show us what you have tried and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please write what does get_no_from_str do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly the function `get_no_from_str` does but I suppose it will return something but I think this will solve your issue

based on your code:

```
university_rank_s = "#StudyOrganisationLocation .OrganisationRanking"
university_rank_st = [x.text.strip() for x in page.select(university_rank_s)[0::2]] if page.select(university_rank_s) else 'N/A'
university_rank = get_no_from_str(university_rank_st)
```

this will get the number 2 child of a parent element data

Comment: def get_no_from_str(x):
    result = "N/A"
    s = re.search(r"[0-9]{1,5}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?", x)
    if s:
        result = s.group()
    return result

Comment: i tried this code but will get all of the li vlaues

Answer (score 0):

When you select the elements, write recursive= False
It will select all parent elements